# Case shell command not working in terminal

Tags: windows, shell, operating-system

Trying to figure out operating system to run a command in my package. Found this :

```
case "$OSTYPE" in
  solaris*) echo "SOLARIS" ;;
  darwin*)  echo "OSX" ;; 
  linux*)   echo "LINUX" ;;
  bsd*)     echo "BSD" ;;
  msys*)    echo "WINDOWS" ;;
  *)        echo "unknown: $OSTYPE" ;;
esac
```

I receive : The term 'case' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

But if I run this within a file "sh test.sh" it shows the correct system to terminal.

My operating system is windows.  The question is why is the error being received when i run in the terminal and not from the file?  And is there any way a case command to run in a script to figure out the operating system?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that comes out of a UNIX shell script.

You are running windows.

if you are trying to run that thing with cmd, you're gonna have a bad time.

However, you could install a copy bin /bin/sh on your windows box.  Such miracles happen these days.  Even the crippled operating systems can have a decent shell!